# relative layout position

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a vertical linearlayout, it has inside two linearlayout with diferent elements, I would like to fix the first one to the top, and the second one centered, I'm trying it but doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_bg"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#3b5998"
    >    
         elements
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background_resto"
        android:gravity="center"
    >

           elements
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout
```

Why is it not working? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advice to choose a RelativeLayout for that purpose.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#fff" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will help you to set the exact "relative" position in relation to other views.

Best wishes,
Tim

Answer (score 2):

should use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_bg"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#3b5998"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
        elements
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background_resto"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        >
        elements
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#ff0000" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="300dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In fact this one is even wrong. You're centering both LinearLayouts in the middle of the RelativeLayout (that is wrapping both of them). The first one has to be aligned to the parent's top and the other one into the center-position.

Comment: ohhk that is typo error and just need common sense to make it correct... I think you have ? right?